# subscription inside forkjoin is called only once

Tags: angular, rxjs, fork-join

I have a fork join subscription and inside that I used another subscription. The 2nd subscription is called only for the first time but not on the further updates. Please suggest how to do it.
In my below code **pharmacistRegistrationDto$** subscription is called only for the first time. not every time when it changes.

```
myFunction() {
    const results = forkJoin({
      designations: this.classificationService.getClassificationValuesByTypeCode('DESIGNATION').pipe(first()),
      contact: this.classificationService.getClassificationValuesByTypeCode('CONTACT').pipe(first()),
      securityQuestions: this.registrationService.getSecurityQuestions(),
    });

    result.subscribe(async (result) => {
      this.states = this.cacheService.statesCache;
      this.designations = result.designations;
      this.methodOfContact = result.contact?.map(x => new Item(x.classificationValueId, x.classificationValueName))[0]?.label;
      this.masterSecurityquestions = result.securityQuestions;

// Below subscription is called only once.. not every time pharmacistRegistrationDto$ changes
          this.registrationService.pharmacistRegistrationDto$.subscribe(pharmacist => {
            this.pharmacistRegistrationDto = pharmacist;
            this.securityQuestions = this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.freeGoodSQAnswers?.map(sq => {
              return {
                questionOrder: sq.questionOrder,
                securityQuestionText: this.masterSecurityquestions?.find(q => q.securityQuestionId == sq.questionID).securityQuestionText,
                answer: sq.answer
              };
            });
            this.designation = this.designations.find(d => d.classificationValueId == this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.designationClassificationValueID)?.classificationValueName;
            this.isTermsAndConditionsDisabled = !(this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.userTermConditions && this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.userTermConditions[0]?.isAccepted);
            this.initForm();
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: Maybe error?  Errors ends the stream right away.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using forkJoin, this is the expected behavior as forkjoin will emit only once when all the observables it is watching have emitted.

Now to solve your problem, you could implement something like this

```
// Create a new Subject which will only emit once your forkJoin is complete
const startListener = new Subject();

function myFunction() {
    const results = forkJoin({
        designations: this.classificationService.getClassificationValuesByTypeCode('DESIGNATION').pipe(first()),
        contact: this.classificationService.getClassificationValuesByTypeCode('CONTACT').pipe(first()),
        securityQuestions: this.registrationService.getSecurityQuestions(),
    });

    results.subscribe(async (result) => {
        this.states = this.cacheService.statesCache;
        this.designations = result.designations;
        this.methodOfContact = result.contact?.map(x => new Item(x.classificationValueId, x.classificationValueName))[0]?.label;
        this.masterSecurityquestions = result.securityQuestions;
        // The subject emits when the forJoin is completed
        this.startListener.next(true);
     
    });
}

// This function contains your pharmacistRegistrationDto subscription
// and this will start listening for new updates, as soon as your above forkJoin 
// emits.

function ListenerFn() {
    // this filter on startListerner allows you to only start listening on 
    // pharmacistRegistrationDto only after it becomes true
    this.startListener.pipe(filter(r => r)).mergeMap()
    this.registrationService.pharmacistRegistrationDto$.subscribe(pharmacist => {
        this.pharmacistRegistrationDto = pharmacist;
        this.securityQuestions = this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.freeGoodSQAnswers?.map(sq => 
            ({
                questionOrder: sq.questionOrder,
                securityQuestionText: this.masterSecurityquestions?.find(q => 
                    q.securityQuestionId === sq.questionID).securityQuestionText,
                answer: sq.answer
            })
        );
        this.designation = this.designations.find(
            d => d.classificationValueId === this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.designationClassificationValueID)?.classificationValueName;
        this.isTermsAndConditionsDisabled = !(this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.userTermConditions && 
            this.pharmacistRegistrationDto?.userTermConditions[0]?.isAccepted);
        this.initForm();
    });
}
```

The above changes will ensure that pharmacistRegistrationDto subscription only starts once your myFunction is executed, and then it keeps also listening to any new changes that are emitted for pharmacistRegistrationDto

Answer (score 0):

It is the intended behavior for forkjoin to emit only once.

If you want the subscription to emit more than once, please considere using `combineLatest` : [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest)